# Login control with custom database

Tags: asp.net, database

I have a problem!

I have a database.have two field username and password.

I use Login Control in VS.

And now i want use login control connect to my database.

how i can do it!

Answer (score 3):

You have to setup a custom membership provider and configure it in the web.config file.  Read this: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider

The login control uses the membership provider's ValidateUser method to check whether a user is valid.

OR: override LoggingIn event, override the default behavior to manually lookup the user by user ID and password.  This approach does not need a membership provider.